# GeoPandas plot range problem

Tags: python, geopandas, matplotlib, pandas

I read a `.csv` file with geometry like this:

```py
trajs = pd.read_csv("trajs.csv")
trajs["geom"] = trajs["geom"].apply(wkt.loads)
trajs = gpd.GeoDataFrame(trajs, geometry="geom")
ax = trajs.plot(figsize=(10, 10))
```

But it shows like this:

[image]

But in QGIS, it show like this:
[image]

How can I set the range of GeoPands plot?

Comment: Does it really show up like this in QGIS if you "zoom to layer"?

Comment: It looks like a projection issue. Try to set the correct crs https://geopandas.org/projections.html#setting-a-projection

Comment: Add a sample of your csv to the question

Comment: You have some small geometry around 0,0 coordinates. Most likely.

Comment: That's truly the result of `zoom to layer`, and I didn't see any (0,0)